# drupal_add_js() is working but the js file isnt executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Okay! I already grinding my gears here and alas! I need your help now guys!

OK so here is the situation..

I have a JS that contains a code that should be executed after `element_to_be_click` element is clicked. The code is correct, its running fine, I've tested it, also the correct jquery/jquery-ui file is added.

So, now I have the JS file! So next is I need to tell Drupal to include the JS, so I went to `template.php` file and add the function and added this

```
 MYTHEME_semanticui_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
      drupal_add_js('PATH_TO_MY_JS_FILE', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header', 'group' => JS_THEME));
 }
```

The path to file is correct, I've tested it.

I am so paranoid so I installed a fresh new drupal site on my local then this the same, and to my surprise the JS is being executed correctly!!

I don't know anymore where / what to check to find the culprit behind this!

I've done quit a lot of research, but to no Luck, so here I am, please help me guys! Thanks!

If you need anymore info, just leave a comment I would gladly give it to you, unless, of course, I cant.

**EDIT 1**

So I just discover this, that this is happening when the aggregate css/aggregate js is ON.

Comment: Did you try to refresh the cache and rebuild the css/js aggregate?

Comment: yeah I did clear the cache... anyway, my site going down when I on the advagg module so I need to turn it off anyway...

Comment: how come the `JS` file i created and added to the template using `drupal_add_js` isnt working when advagg is not `ON`

Comment: ok now I understand. so when using `drupal_add_js` make sure in the URL path, it doesn't have any leading slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok now I understand. so when using `drupal_add_js` make sure in the URL path, it doesn't have any leading slash

Comment: Good! then just accept your own answer so it shows as solved :)

Comment: yeah i was just waiting for 24 more minutes... coz it need 1 day before accepting your own answer